# select2 with ajax clear previous responce on focus

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

using select2

```
$("#select").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/getcity",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    delay: 250,
    allowClear: false,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Eevery time i focus it makes request with no params, just url. So if in previous good request i've received good data, it shows in select, on next focus select2 make empty request and clear data in select. How prevent it?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `minimumInputLength` and some other options outside of `ajax`because they are not `ajax`'s options. In your case select2 never gets the option `minimumInputLength` and does ajax calls everytime when it gets focus.

```
$("#select").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/getcity",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    delay: 250,
    cache: true
  },
  allowClear: false,
  minimumInputLength: 3
});
```